# Spin up a report collection node.js app for my executable

Tags: java, node.js, report

I have a java project that runs for a long time since it has a lot of things to churn through (controlling other subprocesses and all).

I would like to display the progress of this executable on a webpage that I can access for the period of execution of the Java executable.

How do I spin up a Node.js server from my java excutable so that if the java executable exits, the server knows to also exit and save the report information so far somewhere. Also, am I doing something that others have done before?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a heartbeat (a signal from your java application), and have the node app look for that (as part of the data it processes from the java application, or as a separate message). When there is no data, you still need to send the heartbeat. But as long as it is a small message, it will hopefully not impact your performance significantly.

Then set the node server up to shutdown (or restart), and write out your exiting data, if the heartbeat is absent for a fixed amount of time.